# AWS sagemaker training data returns UnexpectedStatusException, Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to learn AWS by following tutorial on [AWS website](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/?nc1=h_ls).

I followed each step but step 4c where I train model with data returns error.

`xgb.fit({'train': s3_input_train})`

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sagemaker-xgboost-2022-09-13-14-05-21-675: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_algorithm_toolkit/hyperparameter_validation.py", line 278, in validate
    hyperparameter_obj = self.hyperparameters[hp]
KeyError: 'silent'
```

I searched for solution but couldn't find it.

Does this have something to do with my location? Because I set my region to ap-northeast-2.

Comment: Can you try it without the 'silent' parameter in step 4b? So, the line becomes - `xgb.set_hyperparameters(max_depth=5,eta=0.2,gamma=4,min_child_weight=6,subsample=0.8,objective='binary:logistic',num_round=100)`. Or, you could set `verbosity=0` instead of `silent=0`. The list of hyperparameters for xgboost are here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost_hyperparameters.html.

Comment: @durga_sury Thank you for the comment. I tried it and it works. It seems like parameter `silent` is not valid anymore and changed to `verbosity` right?

Comment: It does look like it!